# Electric Field Inside non conducting sphere

Tags: electromagnetism

Let we have a spherical, nonconducting, and  thin shell of uniformly distributed positive charge Q and the radius is d. **Will we get any electric field inside the sphere whereas we know the  electric field inside a conductor is zero?**

I have seen  some problems that considered the electric field zero inside the sphere due to the charge distribution.

If the field is zero inside the sphere and if we add some point charge in the sphere, then what will be the force experienced by these  point charge?  Will we get zero still?

Comment: Since I cannot do comment so I just comment here. The spherical shell you specified is nonconducting. Why do you mention "the electric field inside a conductor is zero?" Please improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the field inside a uniformly charged thin spherical shell is zero.  Gauss' Law can be used to demonstrate this fact.

If there is no field,  a charge inside will feel no force.  Right?

Comment: The problem is that the shell is nonconducting, then why the field inside is zero?

Comment: Why do you suppose that the charge inside a uniformly charged spherical *conducting* shell is zero?  In both cases, the charge distribution is spherically symmetric, and in both cases Coulomb's Law can be used to calculate the field at any point inside.  Since the charge distributions are (nearly) identical, the results will be the same.  No field inside the spherical shell conductor, and no field inside the uniformly charged insulating shell.

Comment: Late edit:  in the first sentence, delete the word "uniformly"!!